# Key 'rid' not found in <QueryDict: {u'rid ': [u'HRCM']}>"

Tags: django

I have a a url  like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscriber/registration/?rid%20=HRCM
```

I wanted to get the rid value in my view

I did `getrid = request.GET['rid']`  in my view

But I am getting an error like .

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /subscriber/registration/

"Key 'rid' not found in <QueryDict: {u'rid ': [u'HRCM']}>"
```

Also I tried like

`{{request.GET.rid}}`

in my template directly but this is also not working.

Please help me with what might be wrong here.

Comment: Why aren't you mapping an url to this instead of sending it as a querystring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your QueryDict, there is a space after the name `rid`. So try using

```
getrid = request.GET['rid ']
```

to get the value of `rid` from your url.